# How to dynamically sort on different fields in different orders in Groovy

Tags: sorting, groovy

I am trying to sort a POJO on multiple fields with different sort orders using `groovy`. The field names are not known in advance.

I am using following code which attempts to sort the list based on `delLoc` field in `desc` order (appended with `-` in front) and then on `id` field on `asc` order.

```
import groovy.transform.ToString

@ToString()
class SLoad {
    String id
    String delLoc
    int date
}
//String.metaClass.negative  {  return  delegate?.isNumber() ? -delegate?.toInteger() :  0 } //To enable sorting on Strings in descending order
def lst = [
    new SLoad(id: '1005', delLoc: 'EMS', date: 1),
    new SLoad(id: '1004', delLoc: '1-EMS', date: 2),
    new SLoad(id: '1006', delLoc: '2-EMS', date: 1),
    new SLoad(id: '1013', delLoc: '2-EMS', date: 7),
    new SLoad(id: '1002', delLoc: '9-EMS', date: 8),
    new SLoad(id: '1001', delLoc: '7-EMS', date: 9),
]
def ccls = ['-delLoc', 'id'].collect { 
    if(it?.startsWith('-')) {
        return { target-> -target."${it.substring(1)}" }
    } else {
        return { target-> target."${it}" }
    }
}
lst.sort(true, new OrderBy(ccls))
```

I get the following error while using this approach if the filed in POJO is String
`No signature of method: java.lang.String.negative() is applicable for argument types: () values`

So, to overcome I have added `negative` method to `String` class using `meta-programming` capabilities of groovy like follows

`String.metaClass.negative  {  return  delegate?.isNumber() ? -delegate?.toInteger() :  0 }`

I am unable to sort descending using this approach when the sort field contains `String` values

Everything works fine if sort fields contains numbers.

Comment: try returning hash in your negative method override: `delegate?.isNumber() ? -delegate?.toInteger() :  delegate.hashCode()`

Comment: I also though of same, but since I am after `desc` sort, I was thinking of  `delegate.hashCode() * -1`.. Not sure if there is a way of returning opposite of a `String`.